# Copy cell and adjacent cell and insert as new row: Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to copy a cell and the adjacent cell in a row and insert it as a new row with all the data to the right of this cell also copied over. My data looks like this after mining.[image]

and im trying to get my data to look like this:
[image]
the image above is just one record but essentially its moving all the people and their corresponding position in the original row to a new row. In each row there are about 5 employees and their positions.

thanks

EDIT Attempted code for just 2 cols. 1 position. the idea was to create the empty rows and just copy the rest of the data with auto fill, then work from there

```
Sub TransposeInsertRows()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Set rng = Application.InputBox _
    (Prompt:="Range Selection...", _
    Title:="Enter the name col and pos col", Type:=8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    x = rng(1, 1).Column + 2
    y = rng(1, rng.Columns.Count).Column
    For i = rng(rng.Rows.Count, 1).Row To rng(1, 1).Row Step -1
        If Cells(i, x) <> "" And Cells(i, x + 1) <> "" Then
            k = Cells(i, x - 2).End(xlToRight).Column
            If k > y Then k = y
            For j = k To x + 1 Step -1
                Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
                With Cells(i + 1, x - 2)
                    .Value = .Offset(-1, 0)
                    .Offset(0, 1) = .Offset(-1, 1)
                    .Offset(0, 2) = Cells(i, j)
                End With
                Cells(i, j).ClearContents
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Some attempted code please... Cue the helpful comment from elsewhere... Meeting time (I'll review this after the meeting)

Comment: Absolutely, a friend helped me out with some code we did together but I think we went in the wrong direction.

Comment: Does this "In each row there are about 5 employees and their positions." mean that there are always 5 or does this differ? In the example above there are only 4 people and their positions...

Comment: There are always 5. In theory there are more but we can keep the sample set at 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are always 5 people in each row then this should do it:

```
Sub foo()
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LastRow 'loop through rows
    For x = 1 To 10 Step 2 'loop through columns
        LastRow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'find the next free row on Sheet2
        Sheet2.Cells(LastRow2, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, x).Value 'add Person Name to Sheet2
        Sheet2.Cells(LastRow2, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, x + 1).Value 'add position to Sheet2
        Sheet1.Range("K" & i & ":U" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(LastRow2, 3) 'copy range from K to U to Sheet2
    Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant, simple and elegant. I was so close to converting this to CSV and then do the processing. Thanks for the help

Comment: @ZaydBhyat glad to be of assistance.. :)